# Does CompuBERT suffer from the curse of dimensionality?

Tags: information-retrieval

This question is about [CompuBERT](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2936/paper-06.pdf) ([new implementation](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bxYwWzDX3z81S4TwUaTvqZBHtiMOngez)).

I have read textual data have high dimensionality so I would like to know the behaviour of CompuBERT which uses a dot product for question answering.

If I increase the embedding dimension will CompuBERT suffer from the curse of dimensionality?

(I googled for the same question for sentence-BERT/siamese-BERT but there is no study yet about that...)

Answer (score 0):

[The time complexity of matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra) depends on both dimensions $m$ (the number of documents) and $n$ (the number of features). That is to say: Yes, increasing the number of features will adversely effect the speed.

> I googled for the same question for sentence-BERT/siamese-BERT but there is no study yet about that...

I don't assume there ever will be. The above observation is quite pedestrian.